# Textmate HTML 5 Syntax Highlighting

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, textmate, textmatebundles

I'm using Textmate for web development and ran into the problem that the standard HTML syntax highlighting, but also the HTML (Rails) syntax highlighting does not work well with the new "unqoted" HTML 5 syntax.

**Is there a way to make the HTML 5 syntax highlighting work again, even without quotes? Does anyone know a Textmate Bundle that reenables the correct syntax highlighting?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

https://github.com/drnic/html-tmbundle

There are many others on github as well.

Comment: The linked bundle is very good, but unfortunately it does not support the unquoted HTML 5 syntax.